# .NET OpenFileDialog FileNotFoundException in Visio VSTO even though works fine

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vsto

To let the user open Visio stencils in a VB.NET-based Visio VSTO solution, I am using the OpenFileDialog object with some code I found on Stackoverflow.

Even though the dialog works fine and I get the filename of the file the user has selected, also when succesful I get this exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
> System.Windows.Forms.dll

This is the code I use:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

    Friend Function OpenNewStencilFileDialog() As String

    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String

    fd.Title = "Open the Visio Stencil you want to use!"
    fd.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "My Shapes"
    fd.Filter = "Visio Macro-Enabled Stencil Files (*.vssm)|*.vssm|Visio Stencil Files (*.vssx)|*.vssx"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True

    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        strFileName = fd.FileName
    Else
        strFileName = ""
    End If

    Return strFileName

End Function
```

I don't know why I get this error upon succesful selection of a file by the user (selects file + presses ok in the file dialog), when I cancel in the file dialog I get the same error.

Although the code works fine of course exceptions-you-don't-know-why-you-get-them are bad, your insight into why this error occurs is appreciated a lot!

Comment: What value does the `FileName` property return?

Comment: It returns the filename I selected. (including the path which is correctly shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the `OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory` I think, you should ensure the path exists. Can it be, that you are just missing a path separator.

```
fd.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + Path.PathSeparator + "My Shapes"
```

Comment: Rekshino your answer turned out to be correct, adding the path separator fixed it:
fd.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\" + "My Shapes"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0) method which determines whether the specified file exists.

The method returns `true` if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, `false`. This method also returns `false` if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.

To check whether the path contains any invalid characters, you can call the [GetInvalidPathChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-5.0) method to retrieve the characters that are invalid for the file system. To check if a directory exists, see [Directory.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=net-5.0).

Be aware that another process can potentially do something with the file in between the time you call the [Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0) method and perform another operation on the file, such as [Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-5.0).

The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Which path do you mean? It's not clear from your answer and how it should solve the issue the OP has?

Comment: Thank you Rekshino and Eugene there are plenty of things I can check here from Eugene's comments. The initialdirectory seems fine as the dialog opens in the right place and the filename contains the correct path. When I use Visio.OpenEx to open the stencil the stencil opens correctly, I will use the info to see how I can isolate the issue and will let you know what I find. Thank you both!